# Subset a matrix (int, numerical) by condition on few column values

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, subset

I have a large matrix that I need to subset based on the values of columns (latitude and longitude). Here is a sample code of what I tried:

```
> a<-1:100
> a<-matrix(a,c(20,5))
> colnames(a)<-c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5")
> b<-subset(a, "col2">28, select = c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"))
> all(a==b)
[1] TRUE
```

I.e. it didn't work. So I also tried:

```
> library(dplyr)
> b<-select(filter(a, "col2">28), c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"))
```

> ```
> Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
>   no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'integer', 'numeric')"
> ```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the desired output of your example?

Comment: Just the rows where the conditions are fulfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you want to subset the columns based on col2. You need to specify the matrix also in the second argument of `subset` with `a[,colname]`.

```
a <- 1:100
a <-matrix(a, c(20,5))
colnames(a) <- c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5")
b <- subset(a, a[,"col2"] > 28, select = c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"))
```

if you want to filter on more then one columne, you can use `&` or `|` (and and or). For example:

```
a <- 1:100
a <-matrix(a, c(20,5))
colnames(a) <- c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5")
b <- subset(a, a[,"col2"] > 28 & a[,"col3"] < 58, select = c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"))
```

Here is an example with a between condition, this one could also be combined with `&` and `|`.

```
b <- subset(a, dplyr::between(a[,"col2"], 28, 30), select = c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"))
```

Comment: I would actually like to use between conditions if those are possible :|

Comment: I updated the answer and added and example with between.

Comment: I wanted something like > tst=(a[,"col2"] > 22)&(a[,"col2"] <30)&(a[,"col4"] > 64)&(a[,"col4"] <68)
> b <- subset(a, tst, select = c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5")) and this works with your correction thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want to subset matrix `a` based on values in `col2`. You may think of using a combination of `[]` for this.

```
a[a[, "col2"] > 28, ] # values in col2 greater than 28
# output
      col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 [1,]    9   29   49   69   89
 [2,]   10   30   50   70   90
 [3,]   11   31   51   71   91
 [4,]   12   32   52   72   92
 [5,]   13   33   53   73   93
 [6,]   14   34   54   74   94
 [7,]   15   35   55   75   95
 [8,]   16   36   56   76   96
 [9,]   17   37   57   77   97
[10,]   18   38   58   78   98
[11,]   19   39   59   79   99
[12,]   20   40   60   80  100

a[a[, "col2"] > 28 & a[, "col2"] <= 38, ] # values in col2 greater than 28 and less or equal to 38 (i.e. between 28 and 38)
# output
      col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 [1,]    9   29   49   69   89
 [2,]   10   30   50   70   90
 [3,]   11   31   51   71   91
 [4,]   12   32   52   72   92
 [5,]   13   33   53   73   93
 [6,]   14   34   54   74   94
 [7,]   15   35   55   75   95
 [8,]   16   36   56   76   96
 [9,]   17   37   57   77   97
[10,]   18   38   58   78   98
```

Note that the function `filter()` from `dplyr` requires a `tbl` object as argument. Therefore, if you want to use it you need to set matrix a as tibble or data frame before.
library(dplyr)

```
filter(as_tibble(a), col2 > 28)
filter(as.data.frame(a), col2 > 28)
```